# Turn off eclipse auto format when duplicating lines

Tags: eclipse, editor

How can I turn off eclipse auto format when duplicating line ? For example, when I try to duplicating following codes:

```
Object d = new Object(
    45, 45, 45
);
```

I want it's totally the same when duplicating:

```
Object d = new Object(
    45, 45, 45
);
```

Normally I will get:

```
Object d = new Object(
        45, 45, 45
    );
```

They're not the same, some tabs has been added automatically:<. Could you give me a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

This is for Eclipse 3.7.2.
Go to menu `Window/Preferences`, then to `Java/Editor/Typing`.

There, uncheck the `Adjust identation` option in the `When pasting` category.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested it again with the statement you mentioned in your post and it works as expected. I'm on Eclipse 3.7.2, on Windows x86.

Comment: I just surrender now. Lost too much time for this:D.